# Change filename after upload Laravel Stapler

Tags: php, image, laravel, upload

I'm using the Stapler Lib to make the image uploads.

The image's filename is generated by image description field.
After the upload, the user can change the image description and after that, I need to update the image filename.

Is there a way to do this using the Stapler Lib?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do like this

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = Input::file('image');
        //getting timestamp
        $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());

        $name = $timestamp. '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $blog->image = $name;

        $file->move(public_path().'/../public_html/img/blog/', $name);

        }
```

Comment: I'm doing that on store action, now in update action the user can change the image file name without uploading a new one.